# How to do UTC string to Date object conversion?

Tags: javascript, date, time

**CODE:**

```
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var utcString = currentDate.toUTCString();
  var utcDate = new Date(utcString);
  console.log("CURRENT DATE: " + currentDate)
  console.log(utcDate);
  console.log("UTC STRING: " + utcString);
  console.log("UTCDATE: " + utcDate)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
CURRENT DATE: Fri Dec 14 2018 06:19:05 GMT+0545 (+0545)
2018-12-14T00:34:05.000Z
UTC STRING: Fri, 14 Dec 2018 00:34:05 GMT
UTCDATE: Fri Dec 14 2018 06:19:05 GMT+0545 (+0545)
```

Here I converted currentDate to UTCString, and trying to convert UTCStiring into Date Object in javascript.

Now, in the output current date is fine, and when i log utcDate it also is fine, it is showing appropritate UTC time for current system date, the problem is when I concat utcDate object to string (in the last line in code)it prints out same as current date, why is it happening? The value in line number 5 and number 7 in above code should be similar.

Comment: Because one is using *.toUTCString* and the other the default *toString*.

Comment: If you print the date object.. then it will be in the date format. If you are appending a string to it, the javascript converts the date into string which means the readable format. If you want the exact date as a string value then you need to stringify using json

Answer (score 1):

Line three is automatically calling .toString() method, not toUTCString().  The method is inserted at compile time.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this code, it work for me, the result object may not really UTC date but the local date shifted UTC time.

```
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var utcDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```